# Is it possible to create a Collection in MongoDB with no document?

Tags: java, mongodb

i want to create a empty Collection in java. Means a Collection with no document inside.
If i create only a Collection the Collection is successfully created, but i can't find the Collection. E.g. with get a List of all my Collections. The empty Collection is not listed.

But if i create a empty Collection and when i write a document inside and delete the document the Collection is listed.
I think this method is a little bit dirty to create a empty Collection. So have you a better idea?

I have writte a programm in MongoDB and i have the functionality to create your Collection independent before you add a document in the Collection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't really need to create a collection, copy paste from Mongo docs, same principle applies for collections:

> To make a connection to a MongoDB, you need to
>   have at the minimum, the name of a database to connect to. The
>   database doesn’t have to exist - if it doesn’t, MongoDB will create it
>   for you.
>
> There are two ways to create a collection.
>   Inserting a document will create the collection if it doesn’t exist or
>   calling the createCollection command.

But if you really want :

```
db = mongoClient.getDB("mydb");
db.createCollection("testCollection",new BasicDBObject("capped", false));
```

Documentation link for java driver here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But if i used the command from you. I don't see the Collection if i used the method getCollectionNames. The Set<String> has not the new Collection. And the command createCollection want the name of the Collection and a DBObject see the API from MongoDB [link](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/")

Comment: I think option paramas should exists on createCollection to work, i updated my post with an alloc size of 2GB, try and let me know about it.
Yes, you are right, i forgot about DBObject, i'm used with console mongodb.

Comment: I get the error: Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s). If i used this code : db.createCollection("name", { size: 2147483648 });

Comment: db.createCollection("testCollection",new BasicDBObject("capped", false).append("size",2048576));

Comment: You're welcome, and sorry for my mistakes, like i said, i'm used with mongodb console :)

Comment: I only use the information new BasicDBObject("capped", false). I don't need the size. So the information that is no capped collection is the answer.